# Is it possible to add my app to iTunes Connect and put my app binary on hold if accepted the review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I'll clear myself, is it possible to add my app to iTunes Connect and add my binary and if all is good then put it on hold (mean, wait with the publishing, but the app will get accepted and publish in 1-2 weeks)?

Comment: When you submit you are asked to select a release date. This can either be any date in the future or as soon as it's reviewed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the your app release,
because in nearest past i have updated my app and in app control version it will ask me for releasing automatic or i will release after approved,

[image]

Comment: Can I change the release date?

Comment: Yes, you can release your app after approved.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can decide the date of publishing on iStore, and change it whenever you want.

Comment: Once its get approved or I can change it all the way even before get accepted?

Comment: whenever you want, before or after

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you add a new app or want to upload the new version on the app store. You are asked for the two options

1. **Automatically release** - That you want to publish the app as soon as apple reviews the app. (this means app will be immediately become live if apple reviewed your app and don't find any issue)
2. **I will release** -  that you want to make your app live on a specific date. (this means once apple reviewed your app still app will not be live until the user doesn't want)

Hope this will help you. Happy coding :)